# Open New Page in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

How I can open a link in a new Tab/Window and change focus on it?

```
br = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => 'default'
br = Watir::Browser.new 
br.goto('localhost')  
link = br.div(:class, "div").a.href  
br.attach(link)
```

Some alternatives? The `attach` method doesn't exist for the Firefox browser in Watir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end
```

For more information see http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-popups/

Comment: This is for pop-up window and manipulation on tabs, okay.
What about opening link in tab/window like with the right mouse button in browser.

Comment: There should be no difference in driving another window/tab, no matter how it was opened.

Comment: Sorry, I'm don't understand how i can opening new tab.

Comment: Please start a new question and explain the problem there.

Comment: In this question i ask about opening new tab